# Set the view to a specific swipe view

Tags: android

I was able to create the swipe functionality in my Android app after following a few tutorials and now I would like to slightly extend this so that I can display links to all of these views in a grid-type view. So at the moment I can swipe through all of my views (perfect) however I would like to press a button and all the views that I was able to swipe through should appear in a grid-type view from which i can click to get to that view (where i can continue swiping left and right).

I have no idea what to search for, since the swipe view documentation doesn't talk about this, I looked at `setCurrentView` however when I `getPosition` I get a fragment and not a view. What am I looking for here?

Comment: You seem to be looking for [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: @SelçukCihan So then could you show a quick sketch on how to implement this? I can understand from reading that you can create a separate view by writing an adapter however that is just inflating a piece of XML and not actually switching to a different view. From my limited understanding then I would need to hide the swipe view and once a view is needed hide the grid and display the swipe? (Even so I still would need to somehow display the correct position in the swipe view which again(even though i know the position) I am not sure how to tackle